# bower EINVFORMAT Invalid URL format

Tags: bower

Hi I am unable to register a bower package:

```
$ bower register    FSVS git://github.com/lukesnowden/fsvs.git
bower resolve       git://github.com/lukesnowden/fsvs.git#*
bower download      https://github.com/lukesnowden/fsvs/archive/1.0.0.tar.gz
bower extract       FSVS#* archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      git://github.com/lukesnowden/fsvs.git#1.0.0
[?] Registering a package will make it installable via the registry (https://bower.herokuapp.com), continue? Yesn) y
bower register      git://github.com/lukesnowden/fsvs.git
bower EINVFORMAT    Invalid URL format
```

I can't se whats wrong here any help?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bower package names must be in lowercase letters (a-z). You are using a package name which contains upper case letter.
For more info see the [bower.json](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec) spec and the documentation about [registering](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register) new packages.